# Tomcat connectors with async servlet work and scalability

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tomcat

*Notice: I'm not strong in I/O, so in my further reasoning I can be wrong.*

At first, I would like to understand how tomcat connectors work.
Tomcat 9 have 3 connectors:  **NIO**, **APR**, and **NIO2**.

Before writing this post, I read this
[Choosing tomcat connectors](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/TomcatConnectorsEU_0.pdf) and looked [Apache Tomcat Connector Selection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBSWixIwMmU)

In short, I understand this so:

1. **NIO** - in this case we have  selector, which in one thread, sequentially, polls channels. As a result of each poll, the selector
   returns the identifiers of the channels ready for I/O operations.
   The task of the application is to bypass all identifiers in the loop
   and perform the corresponding operations.
2. **APR** - same as NIO, but write in native code.
3. **NIO2** (**AIO**) - interaction based on the use of handlers callback. Each method, such as write, takes in as a parameter to the
   completion handler - an implementation of the interface
   java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler. Method starts the requested
   operation on a separate thread and passes control to the next. When
   the requested operation is executed in full, triggered one of the
   methods given for the start of the operation, the completion
   handler. The main difference between asynchronous and **NIO** is
   that **AIO** works in a multithreaded environment: operation are not
   performed in those streams from which they were launched. Operation
   **NIO** are executed in a single thread by multiplexing channels.

I have the following questions:
**1)** Are there any advantages of **ARP** before **NIO** if I don't use TSL on tomcat? I testing my app after warm up, and i noticed that the **ARP** processing requests more slowly than **NIO**, with occasional pauses in the processing of requests. JIT > native code? Or under certain conditions it can run faster?
**2)** If **NIO2** uses hadnler callbacks, does this mean that i need to allocate more threads?
**3)** Is **NIO2** faster than **NIO**? Because, on the first look, **NIO** thread is forced to explicitly polling the channels, whereas in the case of **NIO2** was initiated by the operating system, not the app itself. My testing confirmed this, but each case is individual, so I would like to know the details.
**4)** All connectors have *sendfile* functional. According to the resource above "[Choosing tomcat connectors](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/TomcatConnectorsEU_0.pdf)", **NIO2** emulates this. What is meant by this? Does it make sense this functionality, if i used Nginx to serve static files?

The biggest surprise for me was that all the connectors are still using blocking operations.
Official documentation [confirms this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Connector_Comparison).
***Read Request Body*** and ***Write Response Headers and Body*** is blocking operations. About this i wants to talk below.

Next I want to understand how all threads works in real app.
For example, i have a 4-core CPU and I choose **NIO** connector decided to set such parameters: **maxThread**="4" and **maxConnection**="1000"

After, i launched VisualVM. These are the threads that interest me:
***http-nio-8080-exec***[1-4], **http-nio-8080-ClientPooler-**[0-1] and **NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller**

As I understand it, ***ClientPollers*** manages non-blocking Selectors for read request line and wait for keep-alive request. ***NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller*** simulates blocking for request body read/response write. But why use blocking operations? Doesn't that contradict this conclusion: "Slow clients do not stall threads"?
After all this brewing question:
**5**) *exec* threads only processed my requests or they also perform the read / write operation from / to the channels? I answer this, because you can imagine the situation, if we have 10 incoming requests, but available only 4 threads to handle requests.

And I have the following assumptions:
**a**) At the same time, the servlet processes 4 requests, but it is still possible to read data (request headers, body) from the sockets for remaining 6 requests (because we have working poolers in another threads). When the first 4 requests are completed, the remaining 6 will already be read all the data and can be instantly processed (in the order of the queue). So, I/O does not work idle.  (But not solved the issue of blocking operations in the ***NioBlockingSelector***)
**b**) Servlet processes 4 requests, but we can't read data from the network buffer for other 6 requests, only the connection is established. It turns out that ***exec threads*** also perform any read operations, so these threads were blocked processing the "user code" in servlet. In this case, i think about ***async servlet***. I identified a thread pool size of 10. And now the long queries in the controller i can define like this:

```
@GetMapping
public Callable<String> longRunningRequest(){
    return () -> {
        // long method
        return "someView";
    };
}
```

So, now ***exec threads*** are always ready for read/write data. 
But what is the difference if I just would define maxThreads=4+10 in connector config? In the case of async servlet, seems that we simply exchanged one thread to another. Or there may be a benefit if for short requests I use ***exec thread***, and for long-running requests use ***async servlet*** with a dedicated thread pool?

Answer (score 1):

That'a a lot of questions for one question.

Briefly:

> Are there any advantages of APR before NIO if I don't use TLS on Tomcat?

None. APR appears to be slightly less CPU-intensive than NIO, but not enormously so.

> If NIO2 uses handler callbacks, does this mean that i need to allocate more threads?

No. You are confused about NIO and NIO2. From the application's perspective, all of these things work the same way. NIO doesn't "sequentially poll all channels". The selector thread essentially issues a `select(2)` and waits for the OS to notify the thread that one or more channels are ready to be serviced. NIO2 works somewhat the same way.

> Is NIO2 faster than NIO?

Not necessarily. Theoretically, NIO2 should be "better" than NIO, but (a) it doesn't seem to perform any better or be any more efficient in its currently form (February 2018) and (b) it's much newer than any of the other connectors, so it may not be 100% reliable in all cases yet. YMMV.

> All connectors have sendfile functional, [but] NIO2 emulates this.

NIO2 cannot use a "true" `sendfile(2)` for various reasons. Clients can call it, but Java will be doing the work, not the OS.

> Does it make sense [to use `sendfile`], if i [already] use Nginx to serve static files?

No. If you have a reverse-proxy serving static files, it will only reduce performance to proxy those requests to Tomcat and then use `sendfile` (emulated or not) to return the data to the client.

> The biggest surprise for me was that all the connectors are still using blocking operations.

Why should that surprise you? The servlet API is built upon blocking APIs (e.g. `java.io.InputStream`, `java.io.OutputStream`, etc.). If you want non-blocking behavior, you'll want to use Websocket.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's hard for me to understand how the NIO concept actually works in practice by looking at stacktrace in debug mode.
I want to understand what I wrote in the 5th question - сan the server read/write data from multiple connections (>4 in this case, almost at the same time), if i only have 4 exec threads?
If these 4 threads are blocked heavy operations, is the server able to read/write? If no, сlients can waste threads. So interesting how to interact _exec_, _clientPollers_ and _blockpoller_ threads

Comment: You should ask separate questions on SO for things like that, and make sure they are specific. If you want a discussion, join the Tomcat mailing list.

Comment: Clients can't waste threads on keepalives, but they can always waste threads on requests bodies. It's called a *slowloris* attack.